# Magento: Editing top navigation sub nav structure

Tags: magento

I need to do a bit of major editing to the sub navigation displayed from the standard Magento top level navigation.

I've gone into top.phtml and found that it calls a function in the core Mage code, Is it possible to have a file in my theme run before this is called or do I have to create a totally custom navigation/use a extension?

Comment: what do you mean a file run before? Can you give me an example of what you are trying to do?

Comment: The menu is shown thanks to the Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation class and some of its function. You can create your own module just to extend this block and adapt it to your needs.

Comment: How much controll would i have extending it? I considered this as an option, but from what I've seen of the method its fairly closed ended. /but what I was ideally wanting was to know where i;d need to put a copy of this file (like when making themes) that would run instead of the standard.

Comment: So i've tried to extend app/code/core/mage/catalog/block/navigaiton.php, however I don't know where i would have to place this new class file? I'm going to be using it only in template/navigaiton.catalog.top.phmtl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To override `Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation`:

in `app/etc/modules/Yourmodule_Catalog.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Yourmodule_Catalog>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
        <depends />
    </Yourmodule_Catalog>
</modules>
</config>
```

in `app/code/local/Yourmodule/Catalog/etc/config.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Yourmodule_Catalog>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Yourmodule_Catalog>
</modules>

<global>
    <blocks>
        <catalog>
            <rewrite>
                <navigation>Yourmodule_Catalog_Block_Navigation</navigation>
            </rewrite>
        </catalog>
    </blocks>
</global>
```

in `app/code/local/Yourmodule/Catalog/Block/Navigation.php`:

```
<?php
class Yourmodule_Catalog_Block_Navigation extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation
{
.... the methods you want to override...
}
```

And that's it.

Answer (score 2):

You're always more than welcome to simply replace the `design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/catalog/navigation/top.phtml` template with your own markup which you can then iterate over as you please.

The Block class already provides some basic methods that can be used to build your nav menu how you like it, such as `getStoreCategories()`, `isCategoryActive()`, `getCurrenetChildCategories()`, etc.

Alternatively, as mentioned by Peter, you can rewrite the Block class to change specific methods or include your own methods which are then accessible from the template file.